# How to Optimize Sqoop import?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, bigdata

What are the techniques which can be used to optimize sqoop import? I have tried to use split by column to enable parallelism and increased the number of mappers based on the table's data volume. Will changing to Fair Scheduler from FIFO will help?  Thanks in advance!

```
sqoop import -D mapred.job.queue.name=$queuename -D mapred.job.name=$table_SQOOP_INITIAL_LOAD -D java.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom -D mapred.child.java.opts=" -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom" --driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver --connect jdbc:teradata://${sqoopSourceServer}/DATABASE=${sqoopSchema} --username ${sqoopUsername} --password ${sqoopPassword} --hive-import --hive-overwrite --hive-drop-import-delims --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --table  "$table" --num-mappers 50  --split-by column --target-dir ${hdfsTargetDirectory}$table  --hive-table ${hive_database}.$table
```

Comment: Check this http://www.xmsxmx.com/performance-tuning-data-load-into-hadoop-with-sqoop/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but i have read in books
For some databases you can take advantage of the direct mode by using the --direct
parameter:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/sqoop \
--username sqoop \
--table cities \
--direct
```

**Hope this Helps**

Comment: Thanks Bhavesh! You are right. However, I think its vendor specific.

Answer (score 1):

Below are some of the common performance improvement techniques for Sqoop

- split-by and boundary-query
- direct
- fetch-size
- num-mapper

  [reference link](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/70258/sqoop-performance-tuning.html)